# How to inspect TCP Header -> Optional Data with Snort?

Tags: ids, snort, packet

I have been looking around for clues on how to define rules, decoders or preprocessors to be able to content-inspect the TCP Header's Optional Data ( The last 0-40 bytes of the TCP Header)

[TCP Header](https://fthmb.tqn.com/O8I6Dt9t5xVrw3UOVnbBUPdKjGs=/768x0/filters:no_upscale()/about/tcp-header-56a1adc85f9b58b7d0c1a24f.png)

Any clues?
Is Snort even able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Snort don't support to check tcp header length.

But if snort connecting to database, it can store optional data of ip and tcp.

[image]